# Unity, Xcode, Compatibility List?

Tags: c#, ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, compatibility

Problem: I am unable build and Run from Unity editor, or attach Monodevelop to a device process.

Specific Versions:

- *Unity5.2.2f*
- *Xcode 7.1 (7B91b)*

I believe this all has to do with compatibility as Unity will spit out the small warning, when you Build and Run from the editor:

```
Unity xcode plugin has not current Xcode in its compatibility list.
 Please launch the project manually
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
```

Where can I find said "Xcode compatibility list"?

Comment: Looks like it's an Unity bug, they claimed to be fixed but there is someone else having the same problem using the same version as you. Maybe try downloading the patch (5.2.2p4)?  http://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/ios-build-and-run-doesnt-work-with-xcode-7-and-7-dot-1

Comment: Gonna give this a try, i've already tried 3 versions of xcode to no avail.

Comment: This got build and run to work so thanks for that, but as for debugging, no dice. Still not letting monodevelop attach to the process

Answer (score 0):

Workaround for whenever in the future this might happen again:

- Open Applications in Finder
- right-click XCode app > Show package contents
- open Contents
- open Info.plist
- copy the DVTPluginCompatibilityUUID string
- In the Finder window, press ⇧⌘G (Shift+cmd+G)
- Enter /Applications/Unity/PlaybackEngines/iOSSupport/Tools/OSX/Unity4XC.xcplugin/Contents
- open Info.plist in your favorite text editor
- find the part with:

  ```
  <key\>DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs</key>
      <array>
          <string>63FC1C47-140D-42B0-BB4D-A10B2D225574</string>
          <string>37B30044-3B14-46BA-ABAA-F01000C27B63</string>
          <string> etc...
  ```
- add a line with:

  ```
          <string>[Paste the copied UUID here]</string>
  ```

  before this line:

  ```
      </array>
  ```
- Save the file, and provide your password to overwrite the plist.

You'll be able to have Unity run the build process in XCode again (after restarting XCode)